# Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 5 on my project and i am new on Rails. When i running

```
rake assets:precompile
```

I got error

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: mycustomize.
```

**mycustomize.scss** is my customize css file which is in `/app/assets/stylesheets` folder.

I searched a solution is change `application.css` to `application.scss` it do works, but i got a new error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] “/stylesheets/application.css”)
```

Anyone can explain and help on this. Thank you!

**EDIT**

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <title>GoalStack</title>
  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

**EDIT2**
Before i add `mycustomize.scss` i use `application.css` which works well on server. I am trying to add some customize layout so i created `mycustomize.scss` and in application.css i add

```
@import "mycustomize";
```

After all of this all works well locally. When i try to deploy to my staging server, i got the error described above.

Comment: show your layout where you added the `application.scss` file. Just the `<head></head>` content

Comment: ok that part is ok. Do you still have the `application.css` file in the `stylesheets` folder?

Comment: yes. I just have `application.css` and got the error. `application.scss` got the latter error.

Comment: as per the configuration you have, you should have `application.scss` file. But now I need to know where do you see the error? In production or development?

Comment: Yes, can you check my *EDIT2*, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120577/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-william-hu).

Answer (score 1):

```
  config.public_file_server.enabled = false
```

did the trick, thanks  Arup Rakshit.